# Kotlin coroutine that repeats with delay until break

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, infinite-loop, coroutine

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and I need coroutine that could be described as while loop like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (SomeHardwareDevice.isInitialized()) {
        updateUi() // UI thread
        break
    } else {
         delay(50) // background thread
    }
}
```

or just like this:

```
while (true) {
    delay(50) // background thread
    if (SomeHardwareDevice.isInitialized()) {
        updateUi() // UI thread
        break
    }
}
```

At this moment I have something like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var done = false;
        while (!done) {
            if (mainActivity!!.isRfInitialized) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    readRfPower()
                    unlockRfControlWidgets()
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            delay(50)
        }
    }
```

But I don't trust it, because I think that delay does not guarantee that code that runs on Dispatchers.Main has finished.

---

Why do I need this?

I have `MainActivity` that in `OnCreateView` begins *Some-Hardware-Device* initialization (device is connected via UART, needs few seconds to initialize). During this initialization user may navigate to a `Fragment` that requires *Some-Hardware-Device* to be initialized to show data from it. If `SomeHardwareDevice` is not ready yet - I have to postpone initial loading data into Widgets on my `Fragment`.

I want to avoid event-driven mechanism that could notify my `Fragment` that `SomeHardwareDevice` has been initialized, because that would be complicated (`Fragment` may not exist yet when `SomeHardwareDevice` completes initialization.

I also want to avoid changes in my navigation, where I could block/disable navigation to fragment before *Some-Hardware-Device* is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like the following:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    while (true) {
        if (mainActivity?.isRfInitialized == true) {
            readRfPower()
            unlockRfControlWidgets()
            break;
        }
        delay(50)
    }
}
```

Please not that the coroutine is launched on `Dispatchers.Main` context, you don't need to switch contexts `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`.

---

If the reason why you used `Dispatchers.IO` is that `mainActivity!!.isRfInitialized` blocks the Main Thread then it can be rewritten as the following:

```
private suspend fun isDeviceInitialized() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    return@withContext mainActivity?.isRfInitialized == true
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
    while (true) {
        if (isDeviceInitialized()) {
            readRfPower()
            unlockRfControlWidgets()
            break;
        }
        delay(50)
    }
}
```

Or we can even simplify it a little bit:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    while (!isDeviceInitialized()) {
        delay(50)
    }
    readRfPower()
    unlockRfControlWidgets()
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a reason why I'm using IO dispatcher. Device is probed with slow UART. Is there any functional difference between my try and your solution with suspend function?

Comment: Well, not much. In your case `delay` is executed after device is initialized (it seems we can omit it), in my case it isn't. I edited my answer with a little improvement.